# Preserve Array of ActiveSheets as Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone can assist me with a sheet array issue I am having.  For background information, the main "template" sheet is copied multiple times as a new input is stored in each version.  The newly created sheet is named after the input.  The inputs are almost random, so defining by sheetname is not an option.

Once the workbook has all of the new sheets added I am trying to isolate a subset of the sheets.  The problem I run into is the sheet numbers (as seen in the project window) don't necessary go in order.  Also many sheets are hidden.

The following code is portion being used to create the sheet array, which breaks upon trying to save the array as a variable (objsheets).

Not sure what I am missing to have this array saved.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Code Below.

Thanks,
JM

At this point the workbook has the "template" sheet copied and has 50 new sheets added (hypothetical number).

```
Sub SheetArrayTest

Dim mySheet As Object
Dim objShts As Excel.Sheets

Dim varArray As Variant

Dim FirstSheetNum As Long
Dim FirstSheet As String
Dim LastSheetNum As Long
Dim LastSheet As String

'Selects template sheet
Sheets("Template").Select

'Selects the first sheet following the template sheet, and is the desired start of the array
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate

'Creates variables for starting point
FirstSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
FirstSheetNum = ActiveSheet.Index


'Loops through each sheet in the workbook following the "FirstSheet" and selects it to create the array
    For Each mySheet In Sheets

    With mySheet

        If .Visible = True And mySheet.Index >= FirstSheetNum Then .Select Replace:=False

    End With


    LastSheetNum = mySheet.Index
    LastSheet = Sheets(LastSheetNum).Name

        If FirstSheetNum < LastSheetNum Then

        'Attempt at preserving the array

        ReDim varArray(FirstSheetNum To LastSheetNum)
        varArray(LastSheetNum) = LastSheet

        End If

    Next mySheet

'ERROR
Set objShts = Sheets(varArry)

...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `Set` keyword to assign to an array.  That's your first problem, and would explain an error on that line.

```
Set objSheets = Sheets(varArray)
```

That line may also fail because the `Sheets` takes an index value, not an array of values.

You're also not preserving the array with `ReDim Preserve` to extend it.

In any case... let's see if we can't figure it out. it sounds like you're trying to store an array of `Sheet/Worksheet Objects`. But your code is assigning a string value to your array (`LastSheet`), rather than an object.

Instead of storing the sheet name (`LastSheet`) in the array, store the sheet itself (unless you really need the index value).

You can maybe modify this:

```
Dim numberOfSheets as Integer

numberOfSheets = -1

For Each mySheet In Sheets

   With mySheet
       If .Visible = True And mySheet.Index >= FirstSheetNum Then .Select Replace:=False
   End With

   LastSheetNum = mySheet.Index
   LastSheet = Sheets(LastSheetNum).Name

   If FirstSheetNum < LastSheetNum Then

        'increase the size of the array
        numberOfSheets = numberOfSheets + 1
        ReDim Preserve varArray(numberOfSheets)
        Set varArray(numberOfSheets) = Sheets(LastSheet)

    End If

Next mySheet
```

You do not need the variable `objSheets` at all.

Comment: Hi DZ, I appreciate the follow up but am having some trouble with your code and some of the comments.  I've toyed with this a bit and the "Set" argument seems to be necessary, plus the ReDim Preserve varArray(numberofSheets) argument breaks with type mismatch with varArray = Variant.

Comment: To completely simplify this, let's say there is a workbook with 10 sheets, and sheets 5 - 10 are already selected.  How can the set of activesheets be stored as a variable so I can select another sheet, then quickly select 5-10 again?

Really appreciate the help thus far.  VBA is clearly not my strength...

Comment: `Dim varArray() as Variant`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub M_snb()
 For Each sh In Sheets
  If sh.Visible = -1 And sh.Name <> "template" Then c00 = c00 & "|" & sh.Name
 Next

 Sheets(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub M_snb()
 For Each sh In Sheets
  If sh.Visible = -1 And sh.Name <> "template" Then c00 = c00 & "|" & sh.Name
 Next

Sheets(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")).Select
End Sub

courtesy of snb